# $a^n+c^n > 2b^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $a,b,c,d$ are in H.P., show that $a^n+c^n>2b^n$, $n$ being a positive integer.

My attempt: $$b=\frac{2ac}{a+c}$$
$$a+c=\frac{2ac}{b}$$
$$(a+c)^n=\frac{2^na^nc^n}{b^n}$$

Don't know how to proceed next.

Comment: What on Earth does H.P. mean? Also, why is there a $d$?

Comment: H.P. is Harmonic Progression. There was another part of the question that required a *d*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For distinct $a,b,c>0$

using AM-GM inequality,

$$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac ab\right)^n+\left(\dfrac cb\right)^n}2>\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{ac}{b^2}\right)^n}$$

Again, $$\dfrac{ac}{b^2}=\dfrac{ac(a+c)^2}{(2ac)^2}=\dfrac{(a+c)^2}{4ca}=1+\dfrac{(a-c)^2}{4ca}>1$$

or $$\dfrac{a^2+c^2}{ca}+2=2+\dfrac ac+\dfrac ca>2+2\sqrt{\dfrac ac\cdot\dfrac ca}=2+2$$

Comment: Thanks. I understood till 'or'. The 'or' part gives us $a^2+c^2>2ca$. What are we trying to say with this?

Comment: @Ramit, I have tried to establish the same proposition in two ways

Comment: Okay, but how do we fit in b there?

Comment: @Ranit, I have consciously eliminated $b$ much earlier